# JSON reformatting in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql

In a PostgreSQL table I have a column with a JSON like:

`{"elements":[{"val":"value1", "column":"column1"}, {"val":"val2", "column":"column2"}, ...]}`.

Is any way to transform this to result set like:

```
column1 | column2 | ...
-----------------------
value1  | value2  | ...
```

I worked around PostgreSQL JSON functions but didn't find an answer.

Comment: You want change your schema? or you want given your current schema change it to a columnar view?

Comment: Second option. I want to get the result set of SELECT query in the columnar view, not just JSON string.

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using? And do you have an upper limit of the number of columns?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name PostgreSQL v.12.2. And  I know, that there is a limit, but I didn't face it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @a_horse_with_no_name proposal:

```
select 
    jsonb_path_query_first(raw_data_1thbase.data -> 'elements', '$[*] ? (@.column == "column1").val' ) #>> '{}' as column1,
    jsonb_path_query_first(raw_data_1thbase.data -> 'elements', '$[*] ? (@.column == "column2").val' ) #>> '{}' as column2
from data;
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The number of columns of a query needs to be known before the query is executed, so you will have to write one expression for each possible column in your array.

With Postgres 12, you can do this with a JSON/Path expression:

```
select jsonb_path_query_first(input -> 'elements', '$[*].val ? ($.column == "column1")' ) #>> '{}' as column_1,
       jsonb_path_query_first(input -> 'elements', '$[*].val ? ($.column == "column2")' ) #>> '{}' as column_2
from data;
```

You need to repeat the `jsonb_path_query_first()` part for every possible column in the array.

The `#>> {}` is there to convert the JSONB value returned by the function to a `text` value.

Comment: I tried this, but it returned the same value for each column.
But change to "input -> 'elements', '$[*] ? (@.column == "column1").val' ) #>> '{}'" did the job

Comment: @A.Sizov: no idea, the above works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ebe43d407c8dea3eb29c53551977b5ba

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_to_recordset` function to convert JSON into rowset. Anyway, final rowset cannot have dynamic number of columns, i.e. whatever solution you choose, you will have to list them explicitly in some way.

For example in select clause when doing manual transposition of 1:1-converted JSON:

```
with t(d) as (values 
  ('{"elements":[{"val":"value1", "column":"column1"}, {"val":"val2", "column":"column2"}]}'::json)
), matrix(val,col) as (
  select x.val, x."column"
  from t
  inner join lateral json_to_recordset((t.d->>'elements')::json) as x(val text, "column" text) on true
)
select (select val from matrix where col = 'column1') as column1
     , (select val from matrix where col = 'column2') as column2
```

Or in `as x(column1 text, column2 text)` clause when using the `crosstab` extension (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44729747/postgresql-query-with-dynamic-number-of-columns)).

Or in somehow transformed or converted-to-xml JSON.

Answer (score 0):

This sample JSON value dynamically unpivoted to `col` and `val` columns through use of `json_array_elements_text()` and `json_each()` functions by this query

```
   SELECT json_array_elements_text(v)::json->>'column' AS col,
          json_array_elements_text(v)::json->>'val' AS val
     FROM tab t
    CROSS JOIN json_each(jsval) as js(k,v)
```

but pivoting the results coming from the above query needs to columns should be listed individually, depending on the number of columns for the resulting query, in a such a way that of using a conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT MAX(val) FILTER (WHERE col = 'column1') as column1,
       MAX(val) FILTER (WHERE col = 'column2') as column2,
       MAX(val) FILTER (WHERE col = 'column3') as column3
  FROM 
  (
   SELECT json_array_elements_text(v)::json->>'column' AS col,
          json_array_elements_text(v)::json->>'val' AS val
     FROM tab t
    CROSS JOIN json_each(jsval) as js(k,v)
  ) q
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=ba835122d36ef374a354f40c940e7869)</kbd>